Azure Function App trying to access diagnostics storage table
We have several Azure Functions deployed into a CAF subscription with VNET integration. We use Application Insights to collect our logs.
In the logs we see that every 10 minutes several requests are issued to access storage tables of the storage account which is attached to the function. These requests do not come from our code. We don't use storage tables, the 403 error apparantly resulting from non existing VNET configuration for tables. Here the requests from the log stream

2024-12-19T08:21:43Z [Information] Request [324dfaa8-04a2-4a4d-ba3a-67835b5201ed] GET https://__redacted__.table.core.windows.net/Tables?$format=application%2Fjson%3Bodata%3Dminimalmetadata&$filter=%28TableName%20ge%20%27AzureFunctionsDiagnosticEvents%27%29%20and%20%28TableName%20le%20%27AzureFunctionsDiagnosticEvents%7B%27%29


2024-12-19T08:21:43Z [Warning] Error response [324dfaa8-04a2-4a4d-ba3a-67835b5201ed] 403 Forbidden (00.1s) Transfer-Encoding:chunked Server:Windows-Azure-Table/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 x-ms-request-id:0cd68d5d-1002-002f-12ef-517789000000 x-ms-client-request-id:324dfaa8-04a2-4a4d-ba3a-67835b5201ed x-ms-version:REDACTED X-Content-Type-Options:REDACTED Date:Thu, 19 Dec 2024 08:21:42 GMT Content-Type:application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8

The table name in the request AzureFunctionsDiagnosticEvents indicate that some diagnostic setting might be causing this, but we didn't find any setting to disable this behavior. What is the reason for these requests?
Please advise.
Update: Diagnostic settings don't have "Archive to storage account" checked:


Did you add vnet to storage account too?

Storage account has VNET, but not for table.

If you have vnet integrated for storage account and func app's also same vent, then give storage table access for function app.

Sure i can give the table access via vnet, but this is not the point. I would like to know how to disable these requests, or why they even occur.

Because, you have enabled logging, the Azure function app is trying to log the events by creating a new table called AzureFunctionsDiagnosticEvents.

indicate that some diagnostic setting might be causing this, What is the reason for these requests?

This happens, when you enable diagnostic setting as below:



but we didn't find any setting to disable this behavior.

You can delete it :

If you do not want to delete it, then integrate vnet to storage account as well and give respective roles to function app to write or access the storage account.
Also refer, my answer for more information on Vnet Integartion.

We don't have "Archive to storage account" enabled, see screenshot.

If thats the case, try adding vnet to stoarge account which you added to function app and then the issue might go
